# How can I get LyX to compile child documents selectively?

Tags: lyx

I am writing a book using LyX. The book is divided into parts which contain chapters. The book publisher, whose LyX layout file I am using, requires the references to be listed by chapters. I am, as a consequence of this requirement, using the **chapterbib** package which does what is required by the publisher. To use the **chapterbib** package successfully, I have to insert the chapter files into my tree of LyX files using  the LaTeX **\include** command via the **Insert->File->Child Document** menu in LyX. However, the  **\include**  command cannot be used within a file which has been included in the master file using the **\include** command. So I am forced to use the LaTeX **\input** command to insert the parts files into the master file; and the **\include**  command to insert the chapter files into the parts files.

The **Master Document Output** window in LyX sees only the names of the parts files which I have inserted into the master document using the **\input** command. The LaTeX **\includeonly** command, which LyX relies on to compile files selectively, works only if the files selected for compiling are included using the **\include** command. This feature does not give me the option of getting LyX to compile only those chapters that I am working on. Does someone have an idea of how I could get LyX to compile my chapter files selectively, from the master file, without resorting to commenting them out at the points at which I include them? Is there a means by which I could have LyX's **Master Document Output** window see the chapter files which I have included in the parts files?

Comment: Can you post a minimal example? Would using LyX branches (see Help > User Guide for more information) solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks  scottkosty. Using branches may help but I suspect it may complicate things a little: I may ultimately require as many branches as I have chapters. A new idea has occurred to me which may help solve my problem. I'll post it once it has proved its worth. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem solved**! Thanks to all those who had a look at my question, especially  scottkosty who suggested a solution. I solved the problem by including the chapter files directly in the LyX master document using the LyX **Insert->File->Child Document menu** facilty. I can now select the chapter file(s) to be compiled using the LyX **Master Document Output** window. The LyX **includeonly** facility does exactly what I want.

There is one small snag left: The **Master Document Output** window displays only the first nine (9) characters of the name of the path to a selected file, even when the window is maximized. This poses a challenge if the (sub)directories which contain the included files share a part of the path name: Several files, the paths to which share a part of the path name, can only be distinguished by some sort of counting.   I pray and hope that the LyX team considers removing this small snag. Otherwise, LyX is a great document processor.

Comment: Glad you fixed most of the problem! For the other issue, we cannot fix bugs that we don't know about. I have not seen this bug reported. Can you please post a minimal example in a new ticket at http://www.lyx.org/trac . The minimal example is important because I cannot reproduce what you've described. I can always place my cursor in-between the column names and and drag to increase the width of the "Child Document" column.

Comment: Thank you very much (once more) scottkosty for educating me. The problem was not a bug! It was my ignorance! All I need to do is to drag the vertical separator bar between the columns to see the full path names to the included files. Great!!! Now I know. Thanks.

Comment: Great. Well in the future please let us know about any bugs you find. We are very interested in fixing them.